# Jmeter - Internet connection lost after setting the proxy to manual on my android phone

Tags: jmeter

Tried to configure JMeter with Mobile Device to Record Scripts for Mobile Application. Facing internet connection issue

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto the device. The file is called **ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt** and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. You might also need to amend your application [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#network-security-config) in order to allow usage of the self-signed certificates

   - add the next line to `application` section of your application [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

     ```
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
     ```
   - add `network_security_config` file to `base/src/{packageMain}/res` folder and put the following content  there

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <network-security-config>
         <debug-overrides>
             <trust-anchors>
                 <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
                 <certificates src="user"/>
             </trust-anchors>
         </debug-overrides>
     </network-security-config>
     ```
3. Build your application in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline)
4. That's it, you should be able to record your application traffic now

Check out [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) article for more information if needed